# How to include only some attributes in Mongoid referenced n-n within to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document

    has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts, class_name: 'User'

    field :username, :type => String
    field :email, :type => String
    field :time_zone, :type => String
```

What I want is when I call current_user.contacts.to_json to get only the username and email attributes for each contact. I tried to override to_json but doesn't seems to change anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand, you can write your query like this.

User.find(:all, :select => 'email, username')